# Build 32bit on 64 bit Linux using a configure script for FFMPEG

Tags: autotools, configure, automake

This question was asked in 2010 without specifying the application. Neither of the answers work for the current version of FFMPEG on a 64 bit Fedora 16 system. They both cause the configure script to generate an error. I would appreciate knowing if and how a 32 bit executable can be generated for FFMPEG on a 64 bit Linux system with configure options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about FFMPEG, but gcc supports the "-m32" option to force it to build 32-bit code.  It might be worth a try to modify your configure script to add this gcc option.